# Node match dynamic url

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm working on an app, where users can add rooms themself.

This means that I have to match all urls with:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
app.route('/chat/:roomName')
    .get(room.list);
};
```

However I need to check if the room exists before allowing users to go there, which I do with

```
exports.room = function(req, res, next) {
Chat.find({ roomName: req.param("roomName")}, (err, chats) => {
    if (chats == 0) {
        res.redirect('/chat');
    }
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
});
Message.find({ roomName: req.param("roomName") }, (err, messages) => {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    } else {
        res.render('chatroom', {title: req.param("roomName"), messages: messages});
    }
});
};
```

When the user hits a url/room which doesn't exist the redirect happens, but then my app crashes with `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

How can I do this the proper way?

Comment: The error you are getting is because you are trying to run res.render after res.redirect. You may only return the response 1 time. try adding a return statement `return res.redirect('/chat')`

Comment: It's the same..

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with handling errors first:

```
exports.room = function(req, res, next) {

Chat.find({ roomName: req.param("roomName")}, (err, chats) => {
   if (err) {
       return next(err);
   }
   res.redirect('/chat');
});

Message.find({ roomName: req.param("roomName") }, (err, messages) => {
   if (err) {
      return next(err);
   }
   res.render('/chatroom', {
       title: req.param("roomName"), 
       messages: messages
       });
   }
});
```

};